# Where can i find a list of styles for setStyle(style, value)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textinput

Some Flash components have the method setStyle(style:String, value:Object). I wonder where/if I can find a list of the styles that are possible to use here?

I want to change the background alpha of a TextInput-component, but can't find the style-name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adobe documentation is pretty comprehensive.

For example, [here is the page for TextInput](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/TextInput.html)

(Click the styles option at the top right to see the available styles - make sure to click Show Inherited Styles so you see styles the control inherits from its base class.

Comment: Ok, thanks, there it was! Somehow i missed the styles-part in the Adobe documentation despite looking there quite a lot. Thanks